# How to retrieve SSL Certificate serialnumber on F5 device using Ansible F5 modules collection?

Tags: ansible, ssl-certificate, f5, ansible-collections

I have the below script that list SSL certificate details except certificate's serial number.
I see that `bigip-device-info` module doesn't support `ssl-certs` serial number.

How do I retrieve the serial number of ssl certificate using f5 modules collection in Ansible ?

```yaml
---
- name: Create a VIP, pool and pool members
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  vars:
    provider:
      password: admin
      server: bip0dcl0
      user: admin
      validate_certs: no
  tasks:
    - name: list the ssl certificates
      bigip_device_info:
        gather_subset:
          - ssl-certs
        provider: "{{ provider }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: facts_result
    - name: display the results
      debug:
        var: facts_result
```

Comment: As you already mentioned, if such functionality is not supported and therefore not implemented in the module yet (see [bigip_device_info.py](https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-ansible/blob/devel/ansible_collections/f5networks/f5_modules/plugins/modules/bigip_device_info.py), line 13735-13766), it might just not be possible to retrieve the serial number with the current implementation of the module. However, since the code seem to be pretty clear maybe one could implement this value.